# Slow development environment (DNN/ASP.NET)?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I have a site that runs off of dotNetNuke with much customization. In production, this site runs fine, speed is relatively optimal, etc. In development, it's PAINFULLY slow (anywhere from 10-30 seconds per action slow). Can anyone recommend any tools/ideas on how to diagnose this issue? The environments are very similar (the dev database is not as powerful as the production one, but it's not enough to warrant this type of delay). I'm looking for something that can help determine all the points of contact for the requests, etc.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try out the following tools:**

**[YSlow](http://yslow.org/)**: YSlow analyzes web pages and why they're slow based on Yahoo!'s rules for high performance web sites

**[PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/)**: The PageSpeed family of tools is designed to help you optimize the performance of your website. PageSpeed Insights products will help you identify performance best practices that can be applied to your site, and PageSpeed optimization tools can help you automate the process.

**[Firebug and Network Monitoring](http://getfirebug.com/network)**: Look at detailed measurements of your site's network activity.

**[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)**

Answer (score 0):

YSlow, PageSpeed, and Firebug are great tools you should definitely use but the fact that you're only seeing the issue in the development environment seems to imply it's not the site that's the problem but something with the development environment. Generally, I find most slowness in these cases is related to Disk and/or RAM issues. Use Task Manager to verify the machine has enough RAM for it's current load. Make sure there's sufficient available disk space for proper caching to occur. You may need a faster hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Run the site lokal in release mode and see if it changes something.

If you can run the live site in debug mode and see if it slows down as much as in the lokal environment.